# Why was this question from guy who stole food off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, reopen-request, offtopic, scope

I came across [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/72409/49564) from a while back. I was surprised to see that it was closed.

Sure, OP made (and has acknowledged that it was) a very stupid mistake. But does that have anything to do with the question being closed? I wouldn't assume it, but I'm struggling to think of any other reason.

This question seems firmly on-topic to me. It's about job hunting, learning from mistakes, the application process, interviews, etc. And OP managed to elicit some excellent answers.

What makes this question off-topic?

Comment: at least 3 of 5 close votes went to [original revision](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/72409/1) of the question. I just re-checked this in my profile: my vote is dated Jul 31 and I am third who voted there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast first vote to reopen.  You've convinced me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when all of the close votes came in, but if you look at the [revision history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/72409/revisions) of the question, it's clear that the original version of the question was off topic. Monica made some good edits though, and I don't believe it is still off topic for the reason given.

However, I think I would still vote this question closed for being a duplicate. We have a few other questions on this site about how to explain getting fired from a previous job.

[Explaining getting fired in job interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/explaining-getting-fired-in-job-interview)

[How do I explain getting fired for a very bad reason to potential employers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/how-do-i-explain-getting-fired-for-a-very-bad-reason-to-potential-employers)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing if it gets reopened I would vote to close it as a duplicate.  Perhaps a mod could do that and just avoid the process?

Comment: Duplicate of the second one sounds reasonable to me.  The "very bad reason" aspect is an important part of the current question.

Comment: I've always wondered what the process should be for a question that was closed for one reason, edited to fix it, but still off-topic for another reason.

Comment: @DavidK if a question closed for some other reason turns out to be a duplicate we should re-close as the dupe instead.  Dupes help with navigation.  Among the other reasons I don't think it matters much, unless the reason used is actively giving bad signal to readers or something.  Sometimes the lines are fuzzy, particularly when "unclear" is involved.

Comment: @MonicaCellio at Programmers I sometimes flag asking moderator to re-close with different reason. It happens when edit makes current reason blatantly incorrect (and when question is not on a way to [auto-deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773)) - _very_ infrequently - once, maybe twice a year